# What is the case, gender and number of seltenen in »in der Wissenschaft gar nicht so seltenen«?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm having trouble with [seltenen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selten#Declension). What does it modify? Not »*einer*« (singular nominative), not »*jener Fälle*« (plural genitive), it could be dative plural »*denen*« but it doesn't make sense to agree with the object of the relative clause within the main clause. (Or does it?)

> Das Ergebnis war purer Zufall gewesen oder einer jener – in der Wissenschaft gar nicht so seltenen – Fälle, in denen man erkennt, was man erkennen will.

Comment: @userunknown: Das sind keine Bindestriche, sondern Gedankenstriche (sie haben nicht nur eine andere Funktion, sondern auch eine andere Länge), und sie machen sich dort wo sie stehen eigentlich ganz gut. Sie umschließen nämlich eine Parenthese. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthese

Comment: @userunknown bislang ich habe gefunden einige mathematischen Fehler, die der/die Übersetzer während der Übersetzung gemacht hat und die im Original nicht war. Ich verstehe Deutsch ganz gut nicht, um zu entscheiden, ob die Grammatik richtig ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It **is** genitive plural:

*jener seltenen Fälle*

plus the information of where the cases are *gar nicht so selten* (in der Wissenschaft).

Comment: ah..., I was declining it in my head as strong inflection not weak inflection

Answer (score 1):

It is important to realise that the entire fragment that is troubling you is an apposition of *jener Fälle.* This could also have been phrased e.g. using a relative clause as follows, but the author decided against it.

> Das Ergebnis war purer Zufall gewesen oder einer jener Fälle, die in der Wissenschaft gar nicht so selten sind und in denen man erkennt, was man erkennen will.

Thus, *seltenen* is a direct modifier of *Fälle* which is in genitive plural. The key here is that you can imagine the entire phrase as being *one* attributive modifier and because there is an article you would use weak declension. Compare below:

> Das Ergebnis war purer Zufall gewesen oder einer **jener** in der Wissenschaft gar nicht so **seltenen Fälle,** in denen man erkennt, was man erkennen will.